# Is Careers profile reviewed by moderators?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

If someone puts inappropriate content into Careers profile by mistake or intentionally, what happens then? Is profile prereviewed by moderators? Are there any requirements (completeness, etc.) for profile to be visible in candidates search?

Comment: Stack Overflow moderators don't have any special access to Careers.

Comment: Tisk... tisk... tisk... What did you do that you are worried about someone finding out? ;)

Comment: If you screw up your Careers profile then you're probably on the receiving end of the damage anyway. So just carefully review it yourself I would say. :)

Comment: I am just interested how it works, how good quality of profiles is acheived. Someone can get invite from SO, register, and create empty useless for employer profile. If there are two many useless profiles the system becomes useless.

Comment: I'm only speculating here but I'd imagine that employers have a mechanism to report users they come across if they choose to do so. Of course Stack Exchange Employees (which is not to say they are necessarily moderators) will most likely have access to all profiles and can take action when they come across something inappropriate. But I wouldn't expect any of them to be proactively looking for bad profiles, they have better things to do. There's probably quality filters in place (similar to questions) but more or less strict.

Answer (score 1):

We do have moderators on Stack Overflow Careers but we don’t actively review profiles. You can always email us at careers@stackoverflow.com if you spot something inappropriate.

Completeness factors into search results, yes. It’s not a question of visibility, it’s a question of strength in particular technologies, as indicated by experience, SO rep, open source, etc. Less strength means a profile will appear lower in results.